# Angular alternative to subscribe?

Tags: angular

I'm using subscribe which is asynchronous and so the counter variable is being returned before getting updated. Is there an alternative to subscribe that will allow me to only return the counter variable once its updated with the value gotten from the backend?

```
makeOffer(product: string, offer: number): number {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', product);
  formData.append('offer', offer.toString());
  let counter = 1

  this.http.post('http://localhost/Project/PHP/negotiation.php', formData)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    counter = data['counter']
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error! ', error)
  });
  return counter;
}
```

Comment: No, you need to deal with the fact that the request is asynchronous somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use .map instead of .subscribe. Later is mainly used if you want the response updated to the DOM.

```
makeOffer(product: string, offer: number): Observable<number | null> {
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('name', product);
  formData.append('offer', offer.toString());
  let counter = 1

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/Project/PHP/negotiation.php', formData)
  .map((data) => {
    return data['counter']
  }, (error) => {
    console.log('Error! ', error);
    return null;
  });
}
```

**Component:**

```
this.service.makeOffer().subscribe((counter)=>{
     console.log(counter);
  });
```

Comment: Hello Suresh Kumar Ariya, i'm having the same issue : I'm using a shared service to pass data via 2 unrelated components and my variable is being getted before it is setted.
I tried to use .map but it no longer exist in Angular 9. Have you any idea what to use instead of it ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly no. The corect way to address this problem is to return observable from the method and subscribe to it where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `map` operator from Rxjs to transform the value the way you want it to be:

For Angular 4:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

makeOffer(product: string, offer: number): Observable<number> {
  ...

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/Project/PHP/negotiation.php', formData)
    .map(data => data['counter']);
}
```

For Angular 5+

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

makeOffer(product: string, offer: number): Observable<number> {
  ...

  return this.http.post('http://localhost/Project/PHP/negotiation.php', formData)
    .pipe(map(data => data['counter']));
}
```

And then in your Component:

```
this.serviceName.makeOffer(...)
  .subscribe(counter => console.log(counter));
```